# linux - bash: pipe _everything_ to a logfile

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin, stderr

In an interactive bash script I use

```
exec > >(tee -ia logfile.log)
exec 2>&1
```

to write the scripts output to a logfile. However, if I ask the user to input something this is not written to this file:

```
read UserInput
```

Also, I issue commands with `$UserInput` as parameter. These command are also not written to the logfile.

The logfile should contain everything my script does, i.e. what the user entered interactively and also the resulting commands along with their output.
Of course I could use `set -x` and/or `echo "user input: "$UserInput`, but this would also be sent to the "screen". I dont want to read anything else on the screen except what my script or the commands echo.

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like typescript?  See `man script` to see.   Things that are written to the terminal, not printed to `stdout/stderr` will not be captured by standard redirections

Comment: Another viewpoint: logging is something the *caller* of the script should control, not the script itself. The script can output all the log messages it wants; let the caller decide whether they go to `logfile.log` or `/dev/null`.